# How to fetch data in a component when props have changed?

Tags: svelte

I want to perform an api call, when the properties of the component have changed. (not only on mount) When I use the code below, the async syntax keeps it from running. What is wrong?

Child

```
<script>
    export let params;

    $: async () => {
      data = await api.getData(params);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I found the solution: https://www.sitepoint.com/svelte-fetch-data/

Answer (score 1):

you could use .then instead:

```js
<script>
    export let params;

    $: api.getData(params).then (d => data = d);
    
</script>
```

Comment: I found this: https://www.sitepoint.com/svelte-fetch-data/

Comment: This example won't update if your props change.